# Using traits and constraints with grails 3.x domain objects

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is it possible somehow to create a trait with fields and constraints for those fields and then create domain classes that implement that trait and pick up the fields with constraints?

I have code that essentially looks like:

```
trait Shared {
  String sharedField

  static constraints = {
    sharedField nullable: true
  }
}

class ImplementingClass implements Shared {
  ...
}
```

Saving an instance of ImplementingClass with a null sharedField is then rejected with a constraint violation.

Is it possible to do this? Is there an alternative syntax that is required to use constraints and other GORM constructs in traits implemented by domain objects?

Comment: Why are you using a trait to add data to a class?   That's not what the field s in a trait are for.  They're essentially private state for the trait, not for the implementing class.   That "sharedField" member's accessors are being mangled in order to try and maintain that private-ness.

Comment: I think the issue is that the static constraints need to be defined in the domain class.

I don't know that it's inappropriate to use traits to add Properties to a Grails domain. That's one of the basic functions of Traits: http://www.groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_properties. Recall that [properties in Groovy compile to private fields with public get/set methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13227508/1524502).

Comment: It is very reasonable to want to define common properties that can be added to multiple domains. I have an AccessControlledObject trait that defines a number of common properties and logic for adding ACL support to a domain object. Very reasonable and theoretically supportable by traits according to http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_properties. In practice however, trying to use traits in a domain seems to be a disaster. Weird compilation errors, bizarre behaviour, all extremely difficult to track down. One is left with reliable subclassing instead.

Comment: Did you try using "importFrom" in constraints in subclasses? See constraints documentation: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I looked at the source code of Grails and made some experiments.

`importFrom(Shared)` will not work because the Grails looks for a `constraints` field via `clazz.getDeclaredFields()` what results in an empty array for traits.

Now you have two options:

1. Make a Java/Groovy Class wich looks like your trait, but only contains the properties and constraints map

```
class SharedConstraints {
    String sharedField
    
    static constraints = {
      sharedField nullable: true
    }
}
```

Now you can use `SharedConstraints` with `importFrom`

2. [Create a groovy script for the constraints](https://web.archive.org/web/20161116104555/http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/hibernate.html#addingConstraints). This feature is mainly used for Java domain classes but also can be used for traits.

Create a SharedConstraints.groovy in the same package:

```
constraints = {
    sharedField nullable: true
}
```

If you use IntelliJ with Grails 3.0 (maybe other versions too) the script must be placed in the resources folder. If you place the file in the src/java folder as described in the Grails documentation the script gets compiled and will not work[image: intelliJ screenshot]

Also note this bug https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10052

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a trait and a class to provide the constraints.
This can easily be extended to have the `Product` class implement multiple traits and related constraints...

```
class Product implements FormatsTrait {
    static constraints {
        importFrom FormatsConstraints
    }
}

trait FormatsTrait {
    String formats
}

class FormatsConstraints implements FormatsTrait {
    static constraints {
        formats nullable:true
    }
}
```

Kudos to @Andreas for the inspiration