# Want to check if object is in groovy list using .contains() or 'in'

Tags: list, grails, groovy, groovyshell

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode;
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes="name")
class Activity {
  public String name
  public buildings = []
  public rooms = [] as Set

  Activity(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

thisActivity=new Activity("activity")
activityRegistry = []

// is false correct
activityRegistry.contains(thisActivity)

// add new item activity2
activityRegistry << new Activity("activity2")

// is true?????
activityRegistry.contains(thisActivity)
```

this code is pretty straight forward, I create an activityRegistry list, I compare empty list to object I created. naturally test fails. I create a new object on the fly using new that I insert into the list. I compare the list then to the first object created, which is not part of the list, and contains, or in passes. could someone shed some light on how? or why?

Comment: That's a list, not an array

Comment: made the tweaks @tim_yates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AST "EqualsAndHashCode" only use 'properties' from the class. Properties, in groovy, are declared without a modifier ('public'), and getter/setter are automatically generated.

In your example, change `public String name` to `String name`.

See : [What are 'properties' in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225599/what-are-properties-in-groovy)