# Groovy gives "No such Property" but its declared in the method: selenium and page object modelling

Tags: selenium, gradle, groovy, pageobjects

I'm trying out a new way to work with selenium. Previously i've used soapui as an IDE and I'm moving over to intellij. Things are a little different working on a real IDE and i dont understand what I'm doing wrong. I think it has something to do with [What are 'properties' in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225599/what-are-properties-in-groovy)

below is my page

```
package pages

import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

class homePage{
    WebDriver driver
    homePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver
    }
    By openLogin=By.cssSelector("#mainLoginBtn")
    By user=By.cssSelector("#userId")
    By pin =By.cssSelector("#password")
    By go = By.cssSelector("#loginBtn")

    WebElement loginBox(){
        return driver.findElement(openLogin)
    }
    WebElement pin(){
        return driver.findElement(pin)
    }
    WebElement userName(){
        return driver.findElement(user)
    }
    WebElement submitLogin(){
        return  driver.findElement(go)
    }
}
```

below is my test case:

```
package tests

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import pages.homePage

class login{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(login)
    WebDriver driver

    @BeforeTest
    void setup(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","c:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
        driver.get("https://somewebsite")
    }

    @Test
    void login2(){
        homePage Home = new homePage(driver)
        Home.loginBox().click()
        Home.userName().sendKeys("user")
        Home.pin().sendKeys("user")
        Home.submitLogin().click()
        log.info "it worked"
    }
    @AfterTest
    void kill(){
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
    }
}
```

So when i run the login2() the driver opens said site and straight away will give me the `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Home for class: tests.login` error. It's there in the method, what am I doing wrong?

I have tried to add `homePage Home` outside the method to no avail. I'm not sure if it helps but here is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'someRandomName'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
ext {
    seleniumVersion = '3.141.59'
}
test {
    useTestNG()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.0.0'
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:${seleniumVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '7.2.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: "${seleniumVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: "${seleniumVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: "${seleniumVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.12.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.12.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with your capitalization. Class names should begin with upper case. It's part of the grammar to determine the difference between calling a method and declaring a variable.

```
class HomePage {}
HomePage home = new HomePage() // conventional
```

```
class HomePage {}
HomePage Home = new HomePage() // fine, but not conventional
```

```
class homePage {}
homePage Home = new homePage() // error - the grammar reads this as a method call:
                               // this.homePage(Home = new homePage())
```

```
// again demonstrating that this is a method call syntax
class homePage {}
public void homePage(def a) { println a + "456" } 
def Home;
homePage Home = 123 // prints 123456, same as this.homePage(Home = 123)
assert Home == 123
```

```
class homePage {}
new homePage() // fine apparently...
```

```
class homePage {}
homePage h; // ... the error is on the variable declaration part
```

Comment: Thank you for such a well written answer. I'll make sure to keep these conventions from now on